# Unidata on Windows 2019

Tags: unidata

recently made a switch from Unidata on HPUX to Unidata 8.2 on Windows. Previously on HPUX we could do a LIST and it would view all results on screen and we could scroll up and see all results. now on windows, when we do a LIST it will output a handful of lines, we hit enter, and then it will output the next set of lines, but we cannot scroll back up to see the first results. we can scroll just fine, it just seems that unidata removes the previous LIST results before outputting the next set of results. any ideas how to retain those results?

ive tried TERM 80,0,132,0 and it outputs everything on a LIST DICT ... for instance, but it doesnt have this same behavior in paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

This is more a question about the terminal emulator used to access Unidata than Unidata itself.  Some emulators have excellent scrollback support (PuTTY, MobaXterm) and some have very limited scrollback support (cmd.exe).

It's sort of a lateral answer, but on windows it can be convenient to have everyone mapped to a share on the server (e.g. \\SERVER\HOLD) and then send the listing to a hold file by adding LPTR or (P. Then open the listing in Notepad++ or your favorite editor, or maybe right into Excel PowerQuery.  As you note, running TERM 80,24,999,0 can be helpful to set the printer width high and 0 means no page breaks.

Answer (score 0):

One other lateral idea, just in case you don't know this option - you can send the output of a query to XML or a delimited format.  For delimited, something like this is the syntax:

`:list FILENAME ATB1 ATB2 ATB3 ID.SUP TO DELIM 9 _HOLD_/Report.xls`

Which will run the query and each column from the query will become a tab delimited column in the extract.  It's tab-delimited, but naming is .xls has a nice side effect of it opening directly in excel, albeit with a warning.

Also want to turn `UDT.OPTIONS 91 ON` so output conversions are applied (otherwise numbers and dates will be in internal format).

The only deficiency in this approach is no headers - wish there was an option to force a header in row 1, if anyone from Rocket is listening :-)